# Extract string from txt file in C

Tags: c, string, char, extract, txt

I have to extract every "Artykuł" from a txt file and number of line with that string. When I try to compile my program I have error: "invalid initializer char str[]=line;" so I don't know how should I assign every word separately from each line to a char table.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1

int getWords(char *base, char target[10][20])
{
    int n=0,i,j=0;
    
    for(i=0;TRUE;i++)
    {
        if(base[i]!=' '){
            target[n][j++]=base[i];
        }
        else{
            target[n][j++]='\0';//insert NULL
            n++;
            j=0;
        }
        if(base[i]=='\0')
            break;
    }
    return n;
    
}
int main()
{
  FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen("dyrekt.html", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
    int n; //number of words
    int i; //loop counter 
    char str[]=line;
    char arr[10][20];
    
    n=getWords(str,arr);
    
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing str as ```char *str = line```? I Haven't looked at the logic for your program but based on the error you said you have this should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

@Ramus05's comment hinted at this, but I'll expand here.  I made a simple test program to test that element of your code.  When I compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* test = "this is a test string";
    char str[] = test;
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

I get the same error you were.  However, this code compiles:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char* test = "this is a test string";
    char* str = test;
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

When I run it, I get the following output:

```
this is a test string
```

So that's how you can fix your issue.

But I'm sure you're wondering why that happens.  Well, the copied string variable (in my case `test`, in your case `line`) is a pointer in memory.  This pointer could point to something of (theoretically) any length.  An array, however, is somewhat different.  It's allocated to be a specific length.  As a result, C doesn't let you initialize it to be something of variable length.

So, for example, the following code is valid in C:

```
char str[50] = "test string";
```

This is valid because the literal string `"test string"` is of a static length.

In your case, you were trying to set your `char[]` to something of variable length, and C doesn't allow that.  Changing to a `char*` fixes this since that's a pointer.  Alternatively, you could statically allocate an array and use `strcpy` or, even safer, `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a large number of issues to correct. Specifically:

1. never hardcode filenames or use *MagicNumbers* in your code. You should not have to re-compile your program just to read from a different filename. Pass the filename as the first argument to your program (that's what `argc` and `argv` are for in `int main (int argc, char **argv)`), or prompt the user and take the filename as input. Instead of sprinkling Magic Numbers in your code (`10`, `20`), `#define` a constant or use a global `enum`;
2. you do not need `char str[]` to begin with, simply pass `line` to `getWords()`;
3. you invoke *Undefined Behavior* reading beyond the end of your array, your loop limits should be `0 <= i < n`, so that means `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` NOT `i <= n`;
4. don't `return 0;` at the end of your read-loop. That means you exit after only 1 iteration is complete;
5. In `getWords()` you must protect your array bounds. What if there are more than `10` words in the line, or more than `19` characters in the word? If you had defined constants for your array bounds, you can simply add the comparison to your loop conditions and `if()` conditions;
6. Don't use `TRUE` for a continuous loop as you loop over `base`, the proper loop limit is the number of rows in your array. If you have `#define ROWS 10`, then your `i` loop is `for (i = 0; n < ROWS; i++)`. You must do the same for your `j` count. If you `#define COLS 20`, your would do `if (j == COLS - 1 || isspace (base[i]))` to protect your column limit while also catching the `' '` for end of word; and
7. you must know whether you are in a word reading characters, or between words reading spaces. Otherwise, if your line has leading, trailing or multiple included spaces between words, your `arr` will hold a `'\0'` (empty-string) for every `' '` encountered. You can simply use an `int inword = 0;` as a flag and set it to `1` (true) when reading characters, or `0` when you encouter a space. Then you only  add a word to your array `if (inword)`.

Now to fix the issue, start by declaring the constants for your array:

```
#define ROWS 10         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS 20
```

Take the filename to read as the first argument to your program (or read from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided), e.g.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    ...
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    // fp = fopen ("dyrekt.html", "r");     /* NEVER hardcode filenames */
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-file");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Pass `line` to `getwords()` and then fix the loop limits in `main()` to display the words and remove the unneeded `return 0;`:

```
        n = getWords (line, arr);           /* pass line, str not needed */

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* i < n, not i <= n */
            printf ("%s\n", arr[i]);

        // return 0;    /* what? you exit at end of iteration */
```

Finally, all of the changes for `getwords()`, including the checks to protect your array bounds can be done as follows:

```
int getWords (char *base, char (*target)[COLS])
{
    int n = 0, i, j = 0, inword = 0;        /* inword is flag for in/out of word */

    for (i = 0; n < ROWS; i++) {                    /* protect array bounds */
        if (j == COLS - 1 || isspace (base[i])) {   /* both ROWS and COLS  */
            if (inword) {                           /* check if inword before adding */
                target[n][j++] = '\0';              //insert NULL
                n++;
                inword = j = 0;                     /* reset inword as well as j */
            }
        }
        else {
            target[n][j++] = base[i];
            inword = 1;                             /* set inword true */
        }
        if (!base[i])
            break;
    }
    
    return n;
}
```

(**note:** you should add additional error handling to the case where `j == COLS - 1` to handle the additional characters that do not fit. You can just discard though the next space with `for (int c = getchar(); !isspace(c) && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}`)

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>      /* use issspace() to check whitespace */

#define ROWS 10         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */
#define COLS 20

int getWords (char *base, char (*target)[COLS])
{
    int n = 0, i, j = 0, inword = 0;        /* inword is flag for in/out of word */

    for (i = 0; n < ROWS; i++) {                    /* protect array bounds */
        if (j == COLS - 1 || isspace (base[i])) {   /* both ROWS and COLS  */
            if (inword) {                           /* check if inword before adding */
                target[n][j++] = '\0';              //insert NULL
                n++;
                inword = j = 0;                     /* reset inword as well as j */
            }
        }
        else {
            target[n][j++] = base[i];
            inword = 1;                             /* set inword true */
        }
        if (!base[i])
            break;
    }
    
    return n;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    // fp = fopen ("dyrekt.html", "r");     /* NEVER hardcode filenames */
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-file");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while ((read = getline (&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        int n,                              //number of words
            i;                              //loop counter 
        char arr[ROWS][COLS] = {{0}};       /* initialize arrays */

        n = getWords (line, arr);           /* pass line, str not needed */

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* i < n, not i <= n */
            printf ("%s\n", arr[i]);

        // return 0;    /* what? you exit at end of iteration */
    }
    fclose (fp);
    
    free (line);        /* no neef for if, calling free (NULL) doesn't hurt */
    
    exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

(**note:** it is a good idea to initialize a 2D array used to hold strings all zero)

**Example Input file**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

Passing the file to read as the first argument:

```
$ ./bin/artykul dat/captnjack.txt
This
is
a
tale
Of
Captain
Jack
Sparrow
A
Pirate
So
Brave
On
the
Seven
Seas.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.